# Thread 1: "[<UIViewController 0x7fa00cf48ba0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key TableView

Tags: swift

import UIKit
import Firebase
import SDWebImage
import CoreMedia

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!

var posts = [Posts]()
var user = [User]()
var CURRENT_USER = Auth.auth().currentUser

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    TableView.delegate = self
    TableView.estimatedRowHeight = 521
    TableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    TableView.dataSource = self
    loadPosts()
}
```

Comment: share me your tableview delegate and datasource methods

Comment: extension HomeViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        let posts = posts[indexPath.row]
        let user = user[indexPath.row]
        cell.user = user
        cell.posts = posts
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}

Comment: what us your load posts function?

Comment: func loadPosts() {
        Api.Feed.observeFeed(withId: CURRENT_USER!.uid) {
            (posts) in
            guard let postId = posts.uid else {
           return
            }
            self.fetchUser(uid: postId, completed: {
             self.posts.append(posts)
             self.TableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
        Api.Feed.observeFeedRemoved(withId: CURRENT_USER!.uid) { (posts) in
       self.posts = self.posts.filter{ $0.id != posts.id}
       self.user = self.user.filter{$0.id != posts.uid}
       self.TableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

Comment: can you remove the table outlet connection from the storyboard and try it again '

Comment: In Storyboard, the class of what you use for your`HomeViewController` is in fact a `UIViewController` not a `HomeViewController`, it doesn't have the correct class. And `UIViewController` doesn't implements `@IBOutlet var TableView`, so when loading the viewcontroller from storyboard, it crashes because in the storyboard there should be a connection to an existing var in code, but there isn't!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, The exception appearing because of inherit Module From Target box in the StoryBoard. Now I checked that box and the exception disappear.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your tableview reference with storyboard. can you please verify the tableview reference is correct. if the problem comes again just try delete the tableview reference from the storyboard to viewcontroller and please try to connect again.

`the problem is storyboard can't find the tableview with name TableView`

please try to delete the outlet connection and try to reconnect it

Comment: I Don't think so that problem is in tableview reference because I recreated the connection many times .

Comment: check the cell identifier name

Comment: Tried again exception again

Comment: have you checked the cell identifier name is correct

Comment: yes, Checked the cell identifier

Comment: in cell for indexPath method try this TableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "here your identifier", for: indexPath)

Comment: can you please add the storyboard image where I can see the tableview propperties. by clicking the right button

Comment: what I suspect is there is some mismatch in your storyboard with viewcontroller that's you are getting the issue please check every outlets in the cell too

Comment: pictures are not uploading here

Comment: please check your storyboard clearly the issue is withe tableview.

Comment: That's what i thought but nothing happening. But connections are good if connections are good then what else?

Comment: please check your tableview residing view controller its name is correct or not. check it with story board